# how to get current device on Mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there  any way to get the device info that user is using?
I just want to know the device is MacBookPro or iMac.
`[[NSHost currentHost] localizedName]` is used to get info from web.

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058151/how-does-system-profiler-retrieve-the-full-mac-hardware-identifi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
int sysctlbyname(const char *name, void *oldp, size_t *oldlenp, void *newp, size_t newlen);
```

Take a look at [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/sysctlbyname.3.html).

```
size_t size;
sysctlbyname("hw.model", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
char *model = malloc(size);
sysctlbyname("hw.model", model, &size, NULL, 0);
NSLog(@"%s", model);
```